# Toyota Tacoma 2007 fuse diagram

Tags: electrical, toyota, fuse, tacoma

I am having bad luck searching online to find a concise fuse diagram for my Tacoma.  I am a little frustrated with the abbreviations that are on the diagram on the box cover.  In particular, I need to locate the tail lights' fuse(s) and I know it is in the second fuse box that is behind the little pocket chamber to the left of the steering wheel but all it says on the diagram are abbreviations like RR etc.

Does have a decent fuse diagram (with full descriptions) or at least know the position of my tail light fuse?

Comment: Check pages 408 and 409 of the owners manual.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 6):

Tail light fuse will be third from the left along the top row.

[image: 09 Tacoma fusebox]

As for a concise fuse diagram with full descriptions...

[image: 06+ Tacoma driver side j/b fusebox diagram]

Will that do?

Comment: Great answer and diagram :D Should help tremendously.

Comment: @Paulster2 Glad to hear it :)

Comment: Thank you for posting the diagram. I'm not a very mechanical guy- pictures help